# OnChildAdded is triggered when a child is updated

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node 'Message'. I have attached a listener to parent of 'Message' so that when a child is added, it gets triggered.
But when I'm adding a child to an existing 'Message' [say- seen:true], onChildAdded is triggered then also.
Am I missing something?
Also, it would be very helpful if there's some workaround to avoid that.
I just need to update a value in a 'Message' without fetching all of the 'Messages' again.
[image]

Comment: Any chance you update the unique key of the message, so updated message is not `.equals()` to its previous version?

Comment: No @M.Prokhorov, I'm just adding a child, and pushing the map via updateChildren()

Comment: I meant whether your message node includes children in its equals.

Comment: No. Message is having: senderId, receiverId, timestamp. I'm adding isSeen later. That's when onChildAdded is trigerred.

Comment: Instead of describing the code, please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to **include** the [minimal code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here that would probably not just include the listener, but also the JSON that you are reading from the database, and  the code that performs the modification.

Comment: Hey Frank, added the json tree for ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing your code, but most likely you are listening higher up in the tree. The `onChild...` methods work on the direct child nodes of the place/query where you attach the listener.

Say you're listening to `/Messages` in the tree.

When a new message is added, your `onChildAdded` method will get called. This is because a new message was added under `/Messages`.

But if you add a new `seen` property to an existing message, that means no new message was added, so your `onChildChanged` method will be called for the message to which you added a property.

Comment: Exactly. But the listener listening to /Messages is getting triggered when seen is added.

Comment: As said, if `seen` is a property under an existing message, it is the expected behavior that `onChildChanged` is triggered. If that isn't what you're seeing, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey @theAshutoshAJ My answer explains how the API works, and why you won't get `child_added` for a listener on `Messages` when you add a property to a specific message. What you're looking for would be `grandchild_added` or `descendant_added`, but that's not part of the Firebase API. Anything else needed here?

Comment: Hey @Frank, I deleted and re-wrote the code, now it seems working fine. Thanks. Not sure if that's a logical error. Closing the thread.